# Change large navigation bar title with animation

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I'm using this function to change navigation bar title, but it is done in the position of small navigation title (in the center), I want it to be done exactly in the place of the large navigation title (with same font and size).

```
func showNavigationTitleWithAnimation(){
    /// Add a custom navigation title
    let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    let titleLabelView = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: navigationBar!.frame.width/2, height: navigationBar!.frame.height))
    titleLabelView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    titleLabelView.textAlignment = .center
    titleLabelView.textColor = UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor
    titleLabelView.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 34)
    titleLabelView.text = ""
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabelView


    let titleAnimation = CATransition()
    titleAnimation.duration = 0.5
    titleAnimation.type = CATransitionType.push
    titleAnimation.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromBottom
    titleAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.init(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)

    navigationItem.titleView!.layer.add(titleAnimation, forKey: "changeTitle")
    (navigationItem.titleView as! UILabel).text = "New Title"
}
```

could anyone help me on that?
Mant thanks

Comment: anyhelp on that?

Comment: i didnt got what you need, can you give me more details like an image of what you need navigation bar to be